# Structure theorem for infinitely generated modules over a PID

Tags: modules, ac.commutative-algebra, decomposition-theorem

This is a refined version of [a question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235938/decomposition-of-pid-modules) I asked days ago and have no answers yet. I am completely illietarte in algebra so, please, don't kill but explain.

The question is all in the title: is there a complete decomposition of an arbitrary PID module into a direct sum of indecomposable submodules? I understand that in general uniqueness and the cardinality of the set of indecomposable submodules are disputable. I just need the existence. Thank you.

**Edit** Thanks for all comments. Maybe I am close to understanding where my problem is. I think what I can always do is the following (I put it for the case of $\mathbb{Z}^\infty$ for simplicity). For every $x\in\mathbb{Z}^\infty$ such that $\mbox{gcd}(\{x_n\})=1$ the cyclic submodule $\mathbb{Z}x$ is maximal. Two such submodules either coincide or intersect trivially. Moreover, there exists by Zorn a minimal set $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$ such that
$$
\mathbb{Z}^\infty=\sum_{i\in I}\mathbb{Z}x_i.
$$
However, this sum is still not direct, because there may be a proper submodule $\mathbb{Z}y$ with $y\in\mathbb{Z}x_j$ such that
$$
\mathbb{Z}y\in\sum_{i\in I\setminus\{j\}}\mathbb{Z}x_i.
$$
For a general PID module you may not have maximal cyclic submodules but infinitely growing sums of cyclic submodules, but the principle is apparently the same. This is too bad :(

Comment: have you read this page?  http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math101b/Chap5.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Now I read it. Still don't see how it answers my question.

Comment: Recall that $\mathbf{Z}$-modules are abelian groups. Consider the abelian group $A=\mathbf{Z}^X$ with $X$ infinite countable. Every nontrivial subgroup of $A$ has a nontrivial homomorphism onto $\mathbf{Z}$, but $\mathrm{Hom}(A,\mathbf{Z})$ is countable. So $A$ cannot be an infinite direct sum of nonzero submodules. Probably it can't be a finite direct sum of indecomposable subgroups (I don't have an argument right now).

Comment: @Ycor: That's correct.  For details, see the second paragraph of my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1575682/module-which-is-not-direct-sum-of-indecomposable-submodules/1575706#1575706).

Comment: There are written many books over abelian groups (I can recommend Fuchs: Infinite abelian groups I, II). This suggests that there is no simple / complete answer on the structure of such groups in general.

Comment: Another excellent book on the subject is Irving Kaplinsky.
Infinite abelian groups. University of Michigan Press, Ann Arbor, 1954.